# What permissions do I need to access a SQS queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to open a SQS queue but I got this error:

```
2019-07-09 07:20:31,855 pid 3604 tid  800 ERROR    connection <?xml version="1.0
"?><ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/"><Error><Typ
e>Sender</Type><Code>AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue</Code><Message>The
specified queue does not exist or you do not have access to it.</Message><Detail
/></Error><RequestId>fa3bf29c-d5ad-525a-aa55-a70297d241fa</RequestId></ErrorResp
onse>
```

I have verified that the queue name is correct.

Here is the permission I granted to the IAM role:

[image]

i.e.

> ```
>             "sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility",
>             "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
>             "sqs:SendMessage",
> ```

If I run the following

```
 aws sqs receive-message --queue-url https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/12345678/my-queue
```

It does not throw any exception.

In my code, I use boto to connect to the SQS queue

```
sqs_conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region(self.region)
LOG.debug("Getting queue for %s" % queue_name)
return sqs_conn.get_queue(queue_name)
```

Did I miss any permission to connect to the SQS queue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I would double check my application configuration if it use the proper sqs name/region/account settings.

Here is an example what permissions you might need to give to your application to work with your SQS.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "sqs:DeleteMessage",
                "sqs:GetQueueUrl",
                "sqs:ListQueues",
                "sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility",
                "sqs:SendMessageBatch",
                "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
                "sqs:SendMessage",
                "sqs:GetQueueAttributes",
                "sqs:ListQueueTags",
                "sqs:ListDeadLetterSourceQueues",
                "sqs:DeleteMessageBatch",
                "sqs:ChangeMessageVisibilityBatch",
                "sqs:SetQueueAttributes"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:sqs:your-region:account-id-number:your-sqs-name"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This will give read/write access to your application, but not administration access.

The aws command you execute probably use your local aws configuration credentials and that's why it does not give any error.

I suspect the main reason here is that boto is trying to list the queue first, before it try use it at all.

More: [Amazon SQS API Permissions: Actions and Resource Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-api-permissions-reference.html)

Regards.